# Can I freeze baked puff pastry?

Tags: baking, freezing, puff-pastry

Can I freeze a baked frangipane puff pastry braid and have it come out right when thawed?  Will it be soggy or change the texture?

Answer (score 1):

I never tried to freeze a frangipane braid myself, but I assume it will be fine. The crust might not be crispy anymore though, a little more chewy and the overall thing might be a little bit drier.

Answer (score 1):

I've frozen cooked puff pastries but warmed them in the oven when defrosted and the pastry has crisped up well. If you don't want warmed pastries maybe if it comes out soft you could crisp for a 10-15 mins in the oven at about 190c and cool before serving. You can then sprinkle with icing sugar/flaked almonds/drizzle icing, whatever suits.